# Adding nested key and values to a dict object

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to add a new nested key to a json object but i can't seem to get it working and not sure what i am doing wrong. I'd also like to know that is the most efficient method for this?

```
def create_file(qle_folder, param_values):
    json_list= []
    files = [os.path.join(qle_folder, f) for f in os.listdir(folder) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(qle_folder, f))]

    for filename in files: 
        with open(filename) as f:
            for l in f:
                doc = json.loads(l)
                target_length = len(doc['targets'])
                if target_length == 0:
                    continue

                labelel_dict ={}
                for i in range(target_length):
                    label = doc['targets'][i]['label'].strip().lower()
                    match = doc['targets'][i]['match'].strip().lower()
                    new_dict = {
                                'type': label,
                                 'value': match
                                }
                    key_value = str(d).strip().lower()
                    key_value = json.dumps(key_value)
                    if key_value in values_dict:
                        value = values_dict[key_value]
                        value = str(value).strip("[]\"").lower()
                        #dLabel = {"distros": {"Tags": { label: []}}}
                        label_dict[label] = value
                        
                
                doc['Options'] =''
                doc['Options']['Tags']= label_dict
                #doc['Options'] = d['Options']
                
                doc = json.dumps(doc)
                print(doc)
                json_list.append(doc + '\n')

  
    return json_list
```

The final file should look like:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "start": 40,
      "end": 73,
      "label": "test:image",
      "match": "the cathedral"
    }
    {
      "start": 40,
      "end": 74,
      "label": "test:text",
      "match": "some text"
    }
  ],
  "Options": {
    "Tags": {
      "test:image": [
        "test 1",
        "test 3",
        "test 4",
      ]
        "test:text": [
        "test 1",
        "test 3",
        "test 4",

      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The value_dict looks something like this and contains a key that is a "type" and "value" concatenated:

```
{"type": "test:image", "value": "the cathedral"}["['test 1']"]
{"type": "test:text", "value": "some text"}["['test 3']"]
```

The error I receive is

```
 TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `d` as a list but then attempt to access it as a dictionary.
That line should be:

`d = {}`

If you need it to be a list, then you need to set the following lines differently:

```
new_dict = {
'type': label,
'value': match
}
```

It also looks like you are trying to replace single quotes with double quotes and I'm not sure why. You can use the `json.dumps(d)` function to return a valid string representation of the dictionary in JSON.

It appears you are converting the values to a string and then evaluating them. As a dictionary you should not need to do that. I dont quite understand what you are trying to do with the key_values part.. Would the following not suffice:

```
for x in new-dict.keys():
  if x in key_values:
    // Do something
```

Comment: key_values only has one key which is a concatenation of 'type' and 'label'. I've amended for the json_dumps. My issues with appending the nested dict for each line in the json file. I've amended the question based on your feedback.